# Destroying data on storage drives via overwrite methods really doesn't work?

Tags: forensics, deletion, data-recovery, disk-image

I'm going to sell a computer hard drive on the Internet, it's a **500GB** SATA hard drive, I really used it **3 or 2 years ago**, I never used it again, I used about 20 or 40% of the space.

I have read about various tools and used [Hardwipe](https://www.hardwipe.com/user_guide/index.html), first I deleted the volume and recreated it, then with the program (option to clean free space) I used the [GOST R 50739-95 method](https://www.hardwipe.com/user_guide/sanitization_schemes.html#gost_r50739_95), when it finished then I did it again with the random method (both It took about 6 hours, in total I spent 2 days on this task, and I had several interruptions so I had to disconnect and continue the overwrite).

I have read an article on the internet (I shouldn't believe everything I read on the internet, but that's why I am asking this question), where it mentions that overwriting these random bytes is not enough and even if I used the *DoD 5220.22-M method* the data could To be recoverable, it mentions that a good method is degaussing (but this is really crazy, that is, a disk that used so little space), is this information really true? Should I use a Gutmann method?

Thanks

Comment: While you can get a brand new 500GB hard drive for under $25, spending two days preparing a used one for sell doesn't sound like a good business idea. If you had anything valuable/sensitive on it, completely destroying it would have been a so much easier choice.

Comment: A single pass wipe is sufficient, the whole Gutmann thing refers to obsolete MFM disk drives, even Peter Gutmann says so. Degaussing would brick the drive as it would wipe the drive control parameters. As Esa Jokinen said, if you're that concerned just destroy the drive.

Comment: Thanks for your answers friends :)